# "What number of president is Joe Biden?" Is this correct?

Tags: phrase-requests, questions, whom

I know that Joe Biden is the 46th president of USA, but if I was to ask this as a question what would that be?

Comment: This sounds fine. Note that [presidential numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_presidents_of_the_United_States) is in part conventional (e.g. Grover Cleveland was 22nd and 24th) so it makes sense to ask for the number rather than anything more complex.

Comment: The problem is "What number **of** president" instead of "What number president?" which would at least net you "He's number 46" or "The 46th."

Answer (score -2):

"**Ordinally**, which president is Joe Biden?" is correct but not common:

OED

> **ordinally**, adv.
>
> Etymology: < ordinal adj. + -ly suffix2.
>
> With regard to, [...] according to an ordinal number, system, etc.; on an ordinal scale; with regard to order.
>
> 1950   Biometrics 6 1   *Subjective appraisals may be quantified by ordinally ranking an entire test series or by scoring each sample individually.*

You should avoid

(i) "**In order**, which president is Joe Biden?" as it does not say how the ordering is to be made.

(ii) "**in order of election**" should also be avoided as some presidents have been elected more than once.

I would suggest

"George Washington was the first President; which is Joe Biden?"

Comment: Thank you for your input! Your suggestion sounds does sound legit. I was discussing this among friends and we feel like there isn't any straight forward way to ask this, otherwise very, simple question - which is kind of strange.